# Enter button don't want to submit form to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, form-submit

I have this form that I need to be submitted when ENTER is pressed. Everything looks fine but it just didn't work. When click search button works fine but I need to work with ENTER button too.

HTML code:

```
<form id="SearchForm" action="mysite.com/search" target="my-iframe" method="post">


<input type="text" id="x" class="dimmed" name="keywords[all_words]" />


<div class="fieldbg"><input type="text" id="y" class="dimmed" name="City[all_words]" /></div>



<type class="btn_search row_right" onclick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit()">
```

I tried with this script, don't work:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   var textbox = document.getElementById('x');
    textbox.onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit();
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using a link to post your form?

Comment: couldn't you do the same with a input type=button?

Comment: It is working by removing the link : <input class="btn_search row_right" onclick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit()">   Strage because on other page (without iframe) works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

first, your link is incorrect : 403 Forbidden;

second, please check that SearchForm id is defined on the page
:)

Answer (score 2):

You could monitor the keyboard input and submit the form when enter is hit:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
       var textbox = document.getElementById('ID_OF_INPUT_FIELD_HERE');
        textbox.onkeypress = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit();
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? What is the ID o the input field you want to monitor for the enter keypress?

Answer (score 2):

For sure your code will not work on IE, try this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   var textbox = document.getElementById('x');
    textbox.onkeypress = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit();
        }
    };
}
</script>
```